# Is there any way to type some text automatically on terminal?

Tags: bash, git, terminal

When I use git via terminal I open a tab dedicated to git command only, then I don't want to type "git " every time. Is there any way to make some text automatically typed on every line?

Comment: In `~/.bashrc`: `alias g=git`

Comment: You're really too busy to type three characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can define every git command as an alias, so that for example typing `diff mybranch` will invoke `git diff mybranch`. To invoke the normal shell command, type a backslash before it, for example `\diff file ../elsewhere/file` invokes `/usr/bin/diff` and not `git diff`.

Put the following code in a file `~/.git.bashrc`. Configure your git terminal to run `bash --rcfile ~/.git.bashrc` instead of just running `bash`.

```sh
. ~/.bashrc
for c in $(COLUMNS=4 git help -a | sed -n 's/^  \([a-z]\)/\1/p';
           git config --get-regexp '^alias.' | sed 's/alias\.//; s/ .*//')
do
  alias "$c=git $c"
  complete -F _complete_alias foo
done
```

The `complete` line requires the [`_complete_alias` function](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias).

Answer (score -1):

I created this .bashrc function that pushes the code and tags it.
All you need to give it is the comment you want for the push.

The alias of the function is "gp" (which stands for git push).

So if you want to push and tag some code all you need after you add this code to your .bashrc is:

$ gp "test my new git push function"

```
gpfunction() {
    git status
    echo [Enter to continue...]
    read a
    git pull
    git commit -am"$1"
    git push
    tag_major_min=$(git tag |sort -V|tail -1|awk -F. '{print $1 "." $2 "."}')
    echo Tag major min $tag_major_min
    latest_tag_number=$(git tag |sort -V|tail -1|awk -F. '{print $3}')
    echo Latest tag number $latest_tag_number
    next=$(echo $latest_tag_number + 1 | bc)
    echo Next $next
    new_tag=$(echo $tag_major_min $next | sed 's/ //g')
    echo New tag $new_tag
    git tag $new_tag
    git push origin $new_tag
}
alias gp=gpfunction
```

This script uses a major.minor.patch version standard and increments the patch version.

You can tweak it as you please.